# AngularJS-Filtering with specific criteria

Tags: javascript, angularjs

would like to ask how can I use angular filter function to filter on a specific field? Below is how I use my angular filter:

```
<div class="memberTitle">Our Members</div>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <input style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 40%;"
                ng-model="searchMember" class="form-control" placeholder="Search members here...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<ul ng-controller="FriendCtrl" ng-init="getMembers()">
    <li class="browseMembers"
        ng-repeat="member in members | filter:searchMember">
        <table>
```

So for example, if I want to filter with username, how should I do it?

Comment: In your ng-model bind to `ng-model="searchMember.username"` instead of `searchMember`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class="browseMembers"
    ng-repeat="member in members | filter: { username: searchMember }">
    <table>
```

If you want to filter the `username` property this should work.